# Question about using PHAuthorizationStatus.authorizationStatus()

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Should I provide a value for the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key if I only use `PHAuthorizationStatus.authorizationStatus()` to check the current authorization status?

Comment: Hey, please provide more details about your goal and what you tried so far. This helps to solve your question quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()` without adding a value for `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, but I can't think of a use case without requesting actual access to the photo library. For requesting this access you need to add the value for `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm building a framework which will collect device's informations. But I got warning from Apple when I try to upload to app store. It said I request access to the photo library. That's why I am confusing.